# Create site collection from REST Api

Tags: 2013, workflow, site-collection, rest

I have read guides like http://sharepointryan.com/2013/09/10/create-a-sharepoint-site-spweb-using-rest-in-spd-2013-workflow/ but that is to help create a subsite and not the actual site collection.

Is it possible to create a site collection using the REST Api? A workflow can be used if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sharepoint web service admin.asmx to create site collection.

Please check following link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcadmin.admin.createsite.aspx